# Form: Keyboard unexpectedly dismissal

Tags: flutter, forms, bottom-sheet, flutter-textformfield

I am using a Bottom sheet in my project and using a form, when I give a form key to my form , my keyboard splashes and disappear quickly

This shows in my CONSOLE
app_time_stats: avg=1118.30ms min=24.14ms max=3052.74ms count=3
D/InputMethodManager(11721): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{f865cd3 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2148 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InputConnectionAdaptor(11721): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on
D/InsetsController(11721): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
D/EGL_emulation(11721): app_time_stats: avg=240.46ms min=14.44ms max=1273.18ms count=7
D/EGL_emulation(11721): app_time_stats: avg=3881.66ms min=1.37ms max=127754.21ms count=33
D/InputConnectionAdaptor(11721): The input method toggled cursor monitoring off

```
    
class ProductModelBottomSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  ProductModelBottomSheet({
    super.key,
    required this.height,
    required this.width,
    this.productID = 0,
    this.productName = '',
    this.productCode = '',
    this.productUOM = '',
    this.productPrice = 0,
    required this.isUpdate,
  });
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final String productName;
  final String productCode;
  final String productUOM;
  final double productPrice;
  final int productID;
  final bool isUpdate;
  final productFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Container(
      height: height * .8,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          ),
      width: width,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                isUpdate == false
                    ? "  Enter item details"
                    : "  Update item details",
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.info,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Form(
            key: productFormKey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [TextFormField()],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: height * .07,
            width: width,
          ),

         
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```